# Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be complex. Assume $\frac {a_n} {a_{n+1}}$ is real and not positive. Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a complex sequence with $a_n \neq 0, \forall n \in \mathbb N$. Assume $\frac {a_n} {a_{n+1}}$  is real and not positive ie. $\frac {a_n} {a_{n+1}} \le 0$, $\{|a_n|\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is decreasing with limit $0$. Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent.

My ideas:

$\frac {a_n} {a_{n+1}} \in \mathbb R \Rightarrow a_n = k \cdot a_n$ for $k \in \mathbb R$ (right?)

$\frac {a_n} {a_{n+1}} \le 0$ if and only if $\{a_n\}$ is alternating (right?)

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n| = 0$ if and only if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ (right?)

Thus I can conclude $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n |a_n|$ is convergent, but this doesn't help me much.

Could somone help me out ?

Comment: What exactly should I divide by $a_0$ ?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac {|a_n|} {a_0} \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n {|a_n|}$$ ??

Comment: So how would you write this ?

Comment: Proving that an alternating sequence is convergent will not prove $\{a_n\}$ is convergent as far as I'm aware of.

Comment: I can say it is convergent, the alternating series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \in \Bbb R$, thus $\frac{a_{n}}{a_{0}}=\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}...\frac{a_{1}}{a_{0}} \in \Bbb R$.

Let $b_n=\frac{a_{n}}{a_{0}}$. This makes sense because $\forall n, a_n \not =0$.
Then since $|a_n|$ is decreasing to zero, so is $|b_n|$. And $b_n$ is alternating since $\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} < 0$. It's not just $\leq 0$ because $\forall n, a_n \not =0$.

So, $b_n$ is alternating and its absolute value is decreasing to zero. Thus its sum is convergent, by [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).
Therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$ is convergent, and so is $a_0 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$.

Comment: How can you conclude $b_n$ is convergent from this test? We know $|b_n|$ goes to zero not $b_n$ ?

Comment: Oh probably because it is real valued only?

Comment: When $|u_n|\to 0$, then also $u_n \to 0$, whatever the sequence $u_n$ (complex or real). Simply write the definition of a limit. Also, the alternating series test does not tell me $b_n$ is convergent, but a much stronger fact: $\sum_n b_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: How do you know bn is monotonic decreasing

Comment: $|b_n|$ is monotonic decreasing, since $|a_n|$ is so.